# Using a table from 1 Stored Procedure which runs only on 1 day of the week as a reference to another Stored Procedure which runs everyday

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one Stored Procedure lets call it ABC, which generates a temporary table ##ref1. This procedure will execute only if the weekday is equal to a MONDAY.

I have another Stored Procedure let call it XYZ, which generates an output table which a union of ##ref1 from ABC and similarly few other stored procedure.

I get an error saying ##ref1 is an invalid object in the XYZ Stored Procedure as ##ref1 is only created on a Monday.

How can I rectify this error in the Stored Procedure XYZ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should provide some code example, data example (##ref1)

Comment: why don't you store the data in ##ref1 in a standard table? temporary tables are exactly that, and should be treated as such

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using global temporary table, why don't you use a physical table.

In your case, the global temporary table must have been deleted.

Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, **and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server**.

> If you create the global temporary table ##employee, any user in the
>   database can work with this table. If no other user works with this
>   table after you create it, the table is deleted when you disconnect.
>   If another user works with the table after you create it, SQL Server
>   deletes it after you disconnect and after all other sessions are no
>   longer actively using it.

You can get more details on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use global temporary table then something like this should work:

```
create stored procedure xyz as 
begin
 create table #result (id int)

if object_id('tempdb..##ref1 ') is not null
insert into #result
select * from ##ref1 

-- do you stuff here
drop table #result
end
```